# How can I step through nested function calls in GDB?

Tags: gdb

Sometimes I want to debug functions like this:

```
my_func1(my_func2(my_func3(val)));
```

Is there a way I can step through this nested call in GDB?

I want to step through my_func3, then my_func2, then my_func1, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What command are you stepping with? `next` would go to next line when debugging `my_func1(my_func2(my_func3(val)));`, but `step` should enter my_func3.
Example:

```
int my_func1(int i)
{
  return i;
}

int my_func2(int i)
{
  return i;
}

int my_func3(int i)
{
  return i;
}

int main(void)
{
  return my_func1(my_func2(my_func3(1)));
}
```

Debugged:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004a4: file c.c, line 19.
(gdb) run
Starting program: test

Breakpoint 1, main () at c.c:19
19    return my_func1(my_func2(my_func3(1)));
(gdb) step
my_func3 (i=1) at c.c:14
14    return i;
(gdb) step
15  }
(gdb) step
my_func2 (i=1) at c.c:9
9   return i;
(gdb) step
10  }
(gdb) step
my_func1 (i=1) at c.c:4
4   return i;
(gdb) step
5 }
(gdb) step
main () at c.c:20
20  }
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Program exited with code 01.
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the where the function definition is in the source code one solution will be to put break point inside that function.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question - it is possible to step into functions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although you may have get your hands dirty with the disassembly.  First try the `step` command (abbreviation `s`).  If that doesn't put you into `my_func3()`, try instead the `stepi` command (abbreviation `si`) to step one instruction at a time.  This may take several invocations, since there can be a lot of instructions setting up the function call arguments and cleaning up afterwards.